# Autofac resolve types in static class of Web Form Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac

The Autofac has been configured in the Web Form application as following.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
BootStrapper.InitializeBizTypes(builder);
builder.RegisterType<Component>().**InstancePerRequest()**;
_containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
```

In a page there's a GridView binding with ObjectDataSource, for ObjectDataSource, the SelectMethod is a method in a static class.

My codes in static class:

```
private static IComponentContext GetContainer()
    {
        var cpa = (IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        return cpa.ContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer;
    }

    public static IList<RoleDto> GetRoles()
    {
        ***var biz = GetContainer().Resolve<IRoleBiz>();***
        return biz.GetRoles();
    }
```

I got below error when resolve the interface.

> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested.
>
> If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally
>   indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being
>   requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario).
>   Under the web integration always request dependencies from the
>   dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the
>   container itself.

So my question is that how to resolve the registered types in a static class within asp.net web form application when the lifetime scope is "InstancePerRequest"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve something from the request scope, you should use the `RequestLifetime` property of the `IContainerProviderAccessor` instead of the `ApplicatonContainer`

```
public static IList<RoleDto> GetRoles()
{
    var cpa = ((IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance);
    var scope = cpa.RequestLifetime; 

    var biz = scope.Resolve<IRoleBiz>();
    return biz.GetRoles();
}
```